# Delivery of Ubuntu 14.10 installation media to clients

Tags: 14.10

Can Ubuntu 14.10 installation media be delivered and what is the price ?

Comment: Read this link : [Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) and more info over [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Canocical Store - CDs and DVDs](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) only 14.04 is available as a CD/DVD for delivery at the time of this answer.
The only way to obtain Ubuntu 14.10 is to download, from [Get Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download).
Ubuntu is free to obtain (minus distribution costs), [About the Ubuntu project](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/).
You can purchase support packages, [Ubuntu Advantage](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/ubuntu-advantage)